# Jsoup parser not working as expected for particular URL only

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to download the page content and then for parsing it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.toysrus.ch/product/index.jsp?productId=89689681").get();
        final Elements elements = document.select("dt:contains(" + "EAN/ISBN:" + ")");
        System.out.println(elements.size());
    }
```

**The Problem :** If you view the source of page content, there is tag exist `<dt>` which contains `EAN/ISBN:` text, but if you run above code, it will give you `0` in output, while it should give me `1`. I have already checked html using `document.html()`, it seems html tags are there, but the tag I wanted is replaced by characters like `&lt;dt&gt;` instead it should `<dt>`. Same code is working for other product urls from same site.

I have already worked with Jsoup and developed many parser, but I am not getting why above very simple code is not working. It's strange! Is it Jsoup bug? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

When using connect() or parse() jsoup will per default expect a valid html and format the input automatically if needed. You may try the xml parser instead.

```
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException { 
        String url = "http://www.toysrus.ch/product/index.jsp?productId=89689681";
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
        //final Elements elements = document.select("dt:contains(" + "EAN/ISBN:" + ")");
        // the same as above but more readable:
        final Elements elements = document.getElementsMatchingOwnText("EAN/ISBN");            
        System.out.println(elements.size());
    }
```

Comment: is there any disadvantages of using `xmlParser` ?

Comment: By using `connect().get()` or parse() you are implicitly telling jsoup to use its htmlParser(). This parser treats input as HTML5, and enforces the creation of a normalised document, based on a knowledge of the semantics of the incoming tags. While parsing HTML5 parse rules will be applied (There is for example a whitelist of tags; unclosed tags will be automatically closed; <link> bla</link> will be converted to <link /> bla and so on)

Comment: The xmlParser() assumes no knowledge of the incoming tags and does not treat it as HTML, rather creates a simple tree directly from the input. Using this parser enables you to parse the input as-is, without applying the HTML5 parse rules. I do not see any disadvantages. If there are some i cann´t tell.

Comment: I think `connect` should also work with `Jsoup.connect(url).parser(Parser.xmlParser())`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put single quotes around the 'EAN/ISBN:' value; otherwise it will be interpreted as a variable.

Also, there is no need to break up the string and concatenate pieces together. Just put the whole thing in one string.

Comment: Please try yourself and then answer, any of your suggestions are not relevant at all. Thanks for your time.